# SqlAlchemy: Convert inherited type from one to another

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I have two different types both on the same database table (single table inheritance):

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    discriminator = db.Column('type', String)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

class Manager(Employee):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'manager'}
    division = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
    role = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)

class Worker(Employee):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'worker'}
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
```

(Yes, I'm using Flask-SqlAlchemy and not plain vanilla) Now how might I go about converting one declarative model to another. That is, what if a "Worker" was promoted to "Manager?" How do I do that? Do I have to write raw SQL to do that?

Sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find it from the Googles. Please note, this is a contrived example.

Comment: I think rather than writing bare SQL, you would just make an instance of Manager and copy over any relevant properties, then delete the original Worker. But that might be tough depending on how many Foreign Keys etc are involved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's kludgy, and it causes a warning, but you can brute-force modify the discriminator column by setting the property:

```
john_smith = session.query(Employee).filter_by(name='john smith').one()
john_smith.discriminator = 'manager'
session.commit()
```

This will cause a warning like,

```
SAWarning: Flushing object <Worker at 0xdeadbeef> with incompatible polymorphic
identity 'manager'; the object may not refresh and/or load correctly
    mapper._validate_polymorphic_identity(mapper, state, dict_)
```

You can just ignore that, as long as you fix the issues it will cause. The *safest* thing is to close the session (`session.close()`) or expunge everything from it (`session.expunge_all()`) immediately after the commit.

If you must, you can fix issues with John's object alone by just expunging John from the session (`session.expunge(john_smith)`). You have to be careful with that; any remaining references to `john_smith` will keep the object, although thankfully he will be detached from `session` and you won't be allowed to do anything with them.

---

I tried the other obvious options as well. Neither worked, but both are illustrative of what SQLAlchemy's `Session` object stores and how:

1. `session.refresh(john_smith)` fails with

   ```
   InvalidRequestError: Could not refresh instance '<Worker at 0xdeadbeef>'
   ```

   That's because SQLAlchemy queries the database for a `Worker` (not an `Employee`) and can't find one by the name of John Smith, because the database now knows that John got promoted due to the fancy new value in his `type` column.
2. `session.expire(john_smith)` succeeds but fails to update John as a new class, and any subsequent access to him will result in

   ```
   ObjectDeletedError: Instance '<Worker at 0xdeadbeef>' has been deleted, or
   its row is otherwise not present.
   ```

   SQLAlchemy still thinks John is a `Worker`, and it tries to query for him as a `Worker`. That's because he's still persisted in `session.identity_map`, which looks like this:

   ```
   {(saexample2.Employee, (1,)): <saexample2.Worker at 0xdeadbeef>}
   ```

   So there's John, listed explicitly as a `Worker` object. When you `expunge()` John from the session, this entry in the dictionary gets purged. When you `expire()` him, all of his mapped properties get marked as stale, but he still exists in the dictionary.

Comment: This is a well thought out, descriptive answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reworking your object model. A sign that the object model would benefit from a rethink is, when one object works just as well as the attribute of another. In this case, `Worker.title` could equally well be "Manager".

Also, Manager.division works better as its own object Division. Not least because a Division would conceivably have a one to many relationship with Worker.

Something like perhaps a `Division` object with a `ForeignKey` of manager pointing to an `Employee` object. The `Employee` object would have a title attribute; in the `Employee.__init__()` you can manually check if the employee is manager of any divisions and then set the `Employee.title` to "Manager" from `__init__()`.

Comment: That's a good suggestion in general. However, while my example is contrived, I still need to know how to do this as my objects are very much not related via some identity column.